# Why is textview.setBackgroundColor not setting the textviews background, except on virtual devices?

Tags: android, if-statement, textview, setbackground

I have a TextView, and I would like to set the background dynamically. But nothing seems to happen when I use setBackgroundColor.

Edit: So I tried using setBackgroundColor on a LinearLayout that I put behind the TextView, but still the BackGround color was not set.

Edit: Turns out it doesn't work on my Nexus 5, but it works on an Android Virtual Device. This is really strange.

Here is my code:

```
headlineTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texthomeworkdue);

        headlineTxt.setText(homework);



        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("UU")) {

            System.out.println(band);

            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }
```

And I checked, and the If statement is being called.

Here is the full code for the Activity

```
import static com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.Due_Today_Fragment.KEY_DATE;
import static com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.Due_Today_Fragment.KEY_DESC;
import static com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.Due_Today_Fragment.KEY_HOMEWORK;
import static com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.Due_Today_Fragment.KEY_TYPE;
import static com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.Due_Today_Fragment.KEY_BAND;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.R;

public class homeworkdueDetailsActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private String background_colors, actionbar_colors;

    private TextView headlineTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            | View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {

            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        String homework = "";
        String desc = "";
        String date = "";
        String type = "";
        String band ="";

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (null != intent) {
            homework = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_HOMEWORK);
            desc = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
            date = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_DATE);
            type = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_TYPE);
            band = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_BAND);

        }









        SharedPreferences sharedpref = getSharedPreferences("actionbar_color",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (!sharedpref.contains("actionbar_color")) {

            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#03a9f4")));

        } else {

            actionbar_colors = sharedpref.getString("actionbar_color", null);

            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(actionbar_colors)));

        }

        android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

        bar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.transparent)));
        bar.setTitle(type);

        String[] separated = date.split("-");
        String year = separated[0].trim();
        String day = separated[1].trim();
        String month = separated[2].trim();


        headlineTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texthomeworkdue);

        headlineTxt.setText(homework);



        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("UU")) {

            System.out.println(band);

            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("UN")) {

            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("UG")) {

            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("TZ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("TQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SR")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SP")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SK")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SF")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SC")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SB")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("PQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("PP")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("PH")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MS")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MR")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MP")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MG")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("ME")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MC")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("HU")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("HG")) {

            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("HF")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DM")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DW")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("EE")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DJ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("CR")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("CQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("CJ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AJ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AN")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AC")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("FS")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("FF")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        TextView pubdescTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textdescription);
        pubdescTxt.setText(desc);

        TextView pubdateTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textdate);
        pubdateTxt.setText("Due " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            | View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {

            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        String homework = "";
        String desc = "";
        String date = "";
        String type = "";
        String band ="";

        System.out.println(band);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (null != intent) {
            homework = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_HOMEWORK);
            desc = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
            date = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_DATE);
            type = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_TYPE);
            band = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_BAND);

        }

        System.out.println(band);

        SharedPreferences sharedpref = getSharedPreferences("actionbar_color",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (!sharedpref.contains("actionbar_color")) {

            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#03a9f4")));

        } else {

            actionbar_colors = sharedpref.getString("actionbar_color", null);

            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(actionbar_colors)));

        }

        android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

        bar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.transparent)));
        bar.setTitle(type);

        String[] separated = date.split("-");
        String year = separated[0].trim();
        String day = separated[1].trim();
        String month = separated[2].trim();



        headlineTxt.setText(homework);

        String color = "#000000";

        headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));


        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("UU")) {

            System.out.println(band);

            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("UN")) {

            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("UG")) {

            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("TZ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("TQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SR")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SP")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SK")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SF")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SC")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SB")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("PQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("PP")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("PH")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MS")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MR")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MP")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MG")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("ME")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MC")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("HU")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("HG")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("HF")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DM")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DW")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("EE")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DJ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("CR")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("CQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("CJ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AJ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AN")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AC")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("FS")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("FF")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        TextView pubdescTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textdescription);
        pubdescTxt.setText(desc);

        TextView pubdateTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textdate);
        pubdateTxt.setText("Due " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            sendMessage();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void sendMessage() {


        super.onBackPressed();

    }

}
```

Comment: That happened to my many times. I don't know why i must say. But, here's my solution: Create a shape drawable just with the color and instead of `setBackgroundColor()` just `setBackground()` or `setBackgroundDrawable()`. That works for me

Comment: @user1903 the problem is eventually each if statement will have a different color, so making that many drawables is going to be no fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I uninstalled and reinstalled my app, and all of sudden it worked! Weird… Possibly Android was keeping my app in memory?

Edit: Turns out it doesn't work on my Nexus 5, but it works on an Android Virtual Device. This is really strange.

Edit: So it turns out that adding the code from the onCreate to the onResume as well fixed the problem. That would also explain why it didn't work on my phone, and was somewhat buggy on my Nexus 5. Seems that it was saving my activity in memory, and would just load the same activity without the changed colors.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            | View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {

            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        String homework = "";
        String desc = "";
        String date = "";
        String type = "";
        String band ="";

        System.out.println(band);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (null != intent) {
            homework = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_HOMEWORK);
            desc = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
            date = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_DATE);
            type = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_TYPE);
            band = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_BAND);

        }

        System.out.println(band);

        SharedPreferences sharedpref = getSharedPreferences("actionbar_color",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (!sharedpref.contains("actionbar_color")) {

            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#03a9f4")));

        } else {

            actionbar_colors = sharedpref.getString("actionbar_color", null);

            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(actionbar_colors)));

        }

        android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

        bar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.transparent)));
        bar.setTitle(type);

        String[] separated = date.split("-");
        String year = separated[0].trim();
        String day = separated[1].trim();
        String month = separated[2].trim();


        headlineTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texthomeworkdue);


        headlineTxt.setText(homework);




        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("UU")) {

            System.out.println(band);

            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bdc3c7"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("UN")) {

            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#95a5a6"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("UG")) {

            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6c7a89"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("TZ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c0392b"));

        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("TQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ef4836"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SR")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#663399"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#674172"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SP")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#aea8d3"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SK")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9b59b6"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SF")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bf55ec"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SC")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#be90d4"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("SB")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#913d88"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("PQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f5d76e"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("PP")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7ca18"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("PH")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f4d03f"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MS")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f5ab35"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MR")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f4b350"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f9bf3b"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MP")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e87e04"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MG")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2784b"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("ME")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f27935"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("MC")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eb9532"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("HU")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3a539b"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("HG")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6bb9f0"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("HF")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#59abe3"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DM")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00b16a"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DW")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e26a6a"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("EE")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f1a9a0"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f62459"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("DJ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#db0a5b"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("CR")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bfbfbf"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("CQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#95a5a6"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("CJ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6c7a89"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AQ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ef4836"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AJ")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f22613"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AN")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0211b"));
        }
        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("AC")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d24d57"));
        }

        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("FS")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e74c3c"));
        }

        if (band.substring(0,
                Math.min(band.length(), 2)).equals("FF")) {
            System.out.println(band);
            headlineTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3a539b"));
        }

        TextView pubdescTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textdescription);
        pubdescTxt.setText(desc);

        TextView pubdateTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textdate);
        pubdateTxt.setText("Due " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

    }
```

Comment: Could be the Android version on your phone.  Sounds like a deprecation issue?

Comment: @MarkBasler eventually I figured it out, the issue was android was keeping my activity in memory, the reusing its previous state. So I added my onCreate code to my onResume and that fixed it.

Comment: Oh got ya.  Sorry haven't had my first cup of coffee.  You should click the checkmark showing this answer solved it then.

Comment: @MarkBasler, it won't let you click the checkmark on your own answer until a day later, thank for the attention to my question though.